# How can access Flutter specific list item from model class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a model class called **Place** and have a list of **place** based on the model class. I use  **Navigator.push** and pass int data from there. Now how can I access a specific list of place where the id is the same as the given id number?

Here is my model class and list:

```
class Place {
  int id;
  String cardImage;
  String placeName;
  String location;
  String country;
  String details;

  Place({
    required this.id,
    required this.cardImage,
    required this.placeName,
    required this.location,
    required this.country,
    required this.details,
  });
}

final List<Place> place = [
  Place(
      id: 1,
      cardImage:
          "https://image1_url.jpg",
      placeName: "Essence Of Japan",
      location: "Tokyo",
      country: "Japan",
      details: "long text"),
Place(
      id: 2,
      cardImage:
          "https://image2_url.jpg",
      placeName: "Essence Of Japan",
      location: "Tokyo",
      country: "Japan",
      details: "long text"),
];
```

This is my Navigator where is pass id as 1:

```
Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DetailsPage(1),
          ),
        );
```

Now I want to access bellow item where id:1

```
      Place(
          id: 1,
          cardImage:
              "https://image1_url.jpg",
          placeName: "Essence Of Japan",
          location: "Tokyo",
          country: "Japan",
          details: "long text"
         ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `places` list is in the screen where you navigate, and the `id` is the id you pass to the screen, you can get the place with that id this way :

```dart
  try {
    var foundPlace = places.firstWhere((p) => p.id == widget.id);
  } catch (e) {
    print('place not found');
  }
```

Needs to be in a try-catch because if the place is not found it throws a `StateError`. Or you can add an `orElse` that will return a `Place` with `null` values, that requires to change the `Place` class and remove the `required` from the parameters. In this case you won't need a try-catch :

```dart
var foundPlace = place.firstWhere((p) => p.id == widget.id, orElse:()=>Place());
```